# WSO2 API manager and Identity Server Integration

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I tried to integrate wso2IS 5.0.0 and wso2AM 1.7.0 by following documentation. 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.0.0+with+the+API+Manager+1.8.0+or+1.7.0

But following exception caused

```
[2016-11-29 15:31:02,320] ERROR - RegistryContext Couldn't find db configuration 'wso2registry'
[2016-11-29 15:31:02,422] ERROR - EmbeddedRegistryService Failed to configure the embedded registry. Invalid data access manager.
[2016-11-29 15:31:02,429] ERROR - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Failed to activate Registry Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to configure the embedded registry. Invalid data access manager.
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.configure(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:167)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.<init>(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.getEmbeddedRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:630)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:563)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:70)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
[2016-11-29 15:31:02,463]  INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2016-11-29 15:31:11,313]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
```

Comment: Please post your `registry.xml`. Btw, why do you use very old versions of APIM and IS?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce an existing environment and I'm going with java 7
below link contains registry.xml  of AM

http://pastebin.com/wWcLBkT0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have removed below section from `registry.xml`

```
<dbConfig name="wso2registry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>
```

Th doc you are referring explicitly says not to do that.

> When doing this change, do not replace the existing  for
>   "wso2registry". Simply add the following configuration to the existing
>   configurations.